# Error message on trying to estimate 95% CI - "Error in approx..(sp$y, sp$x, xout = cutoff) : need at least two non-NA values to interpolate"

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I am trying to estimate 95% CI using the `confint` function for a generalized linear model. While I am able to estimate Odds ratio using the `coef` function but on using the `confint` function, I get the message

> Error in approx(sp$y, sp$x, xout = cutoff) :
> need at least two non-NA values to interpolate

The following are the Coefficients for which I am trying to calculate 95% CI.

The original data has no NA values so I am not sure why this error is showing up

```
 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
  1.05649    0.30658   3.446 0.000569 ***                                        
 -0.58348    0.49948  -1.168 0.242744    
 -0.77959    1.47292  -0.529 0.596609    
-18.50414 6522.63862  -0.003 0.997736    
 -0.82328    0.49102  -1.677 0.093608 .  
-13.95852 4036.00271  -0.003 0.997241    
  0.53909    0.83073   0.649 0.516376    
 -0.55514    0.46189  -1.202 0.229408    
 17.75434 6522.63863   0.003 0.997828    
-15.97188 1051.20492  -0.015 0.987878    
 -0.16589    0.43172  -0.384 0.700792    
 31.60387 1459.11421   0.022 0.982719    
 -0.42616    0.43637  -0.977 0.328766    
 1.10179     1.19697   0.920 0.357321    
 0.52345     1.23113   0.425 0.670705    
 0.50791     1.54670   0.328 0.742621    
 0.19881     0.34945   0.569 0.569403    
-0.07887     0.49769  -0.158 0.874085    
 0.05958     0.36780   0.162 0.871306    
-0.61339     0.38503  -1.593 0.111142
```

I tried to compute 95% CI using the above coefficients using the `cofit` function.

Comment: So it got fixed, there were some data rows which were not a part of the model but were interfering with the calculation of 95% CI; on deleting them, everything worked out just fine! :)